# <div> as child element of <nav> considered bad practice?

Tags: html, nav

I was wondering if putting `<div>` inside `<nav>` is considered bad practice, since most of the time I see `<nav>` used in connection with `<ul>` and `<li>` elements.

For example:

```html
<nav id="content" class="box_navi">
    <div><a href=""><img src="img/projekte250.png" alt="Projekte" title="Projekte"/></a></div>
    ...
    <div><a href=""><img src="img/shop250.png" alt="Shop" title="Shop"/></a></div>
</nav>
```

I understand that `<ul>` is used to maintain readability of the navigation if css would be disabled (or when printed).
In my case I use images as navigation, so I don't see an advantage in using `<li>` over `<div>` also I did not encounter any problems with the way it is now.

Am I missing an important point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is great emphasis on correct semantics in HTML.

You are using `<nav>` because all the elements with in it are for navigation.
There nothing fundamentally wrong with using `<div>` elements however you should always think about the purpose of each element you using so if you make a (ordered) list of something use `<ol>` if you use unordered list `<ul>` and so on.

A lot of website use `<ul>` because navigation is literally a list of links which makes it correct.

You menu is a list of images so you can use `<ul>` there too but I don't think  you'll have any rendering problems using `<div>` elements